# Pandas: Row reduction via Groupby

Tags: python, pandas

For an example, I have a simple DataFrame like:

| index | data1 | replace_me | agg_me | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | (+) | 25 | 1 |
| 2 | 200 | (-) | 35 | 2 |
| 3 | 200 | (+) | 45 | 2 |
| 4 | 300 | (+) | 55 | 3 |
| 5 | 400 | (+) | 10 | 4 |
| 6 | 400 | (+) | 10 | 4 |
| 7 | 400 | (-) | 10 | 4 |
| 8 | 400 | (-) | 10 | 4 |

I am trying to aggregate some rows together, whereby there exists a len(groupby of ID) > 1.   In the cases where len(groupby ID)  > 1, I am looking to:

1. Add column "agg_me" together
2. Replace (-) and (+) with (=)
3. Enter the (min(agg_me) / sum(agg_me)) into a new column called "Percent".
4. Do such that it only "pairs" off rows, ie, it doesnt collapse 4 rows -> 1.
   So as a result:

| index | data1 | replace_me | agg_me | ID | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | (+) | 25 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 200 | (=) | 80 | 2 | 0.4375 |
| 4 | 300 | (+) | 55 | 3 | 0 |
| 5 | 400 | (=) | 20 | 4 | 0.5 |
| 6 | 400 | (=) | 20 | 4 | 0.5 |

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Note:  Made addition to original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
vc = df['ID'].map(df['ID'].value_counts()).gt(1)

pd.concat([df.loc[~vc],
    df.loc[vc]
    .groupby(['ID',df.groupby('ID').cumcount().floordiv(2)]).agg(
        index = ('index','first'),
        data1 = ('data1','first'),
        replace_me = ('replace_me',lambda x: '(=)'),
        agg_me = ('agg_me','sum'),
        Percent = ('agg_me',lambda x: x.min()/x.sum()))
            .reset_index(level=0)]).fillna(0).sort_values('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   index  data1 replace_me  agg_me  ID  Percent
0      1    100        (+)      25   1   0.0000
1      2    200        (=)      80   2   0.4375
2      4    300        (+)      55   3   0.0000
3      5    400        (=)      20   4   0.5000
4      7    400        (=)      20   4   0.5000
```